# Deallocating memory for array within a linked chain struct

Tags: c, struct, free

I am trying to deallocate the memory used by different struct that are part of a linked chain.
The **dumpGroupingOrder()** function is supposed to deallocate the memory used, however the whole program ceases to function once it is used. Without it the program works even though there are memory leaks, see the output of valgrind below:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 48 bytes in 1 blocks
indirectly lost: 328 bytes in 11 blocks
```

With it there are no memory leaks, but I get a **double free or corruption (out)** error message instead and the following error message from valgrind:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
   at 0x48399AB: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
   by 0x10929A: dumpGroupingOrder (code-stack.c:54)
   by 0x10952F: main (code-stack.c:88)
   Address 0x1fff0000b0 is on thread 1's stack
   in frame #2, created by main (code-stack.c:74)
```

Below the entire code used as a MWE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


struct groupingOrder {
  int *taxa;
  size_t groupeSize;
  long double distance;
  struct groupingOrder* next;
};


void addGroup( struct groupingOrder* HEAD, int * groupe, size_t groupeSize, long double distance ) {

  struct groupingOrder* temp = HEAD;
  // Moving the last unit structure
  while( temp->next != NULL ) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  // Allocating space for the unit structure
  struct groupingOrder* nouveau = malloc( sizeof( struct groupingOrder ) );
  nouveau->distance = distance;
  nouveau->groupeSize = groupeSize;
  // Allocating variable space for the list of taxa to be stored
  nouveau->taxa = malloc( groupeSize * sizeof( int ) );
  for( int i = 0; i < groupeSize; i++) {
    nouveau->taxa[i] = groupe[i];
  }
  // Linking the new unit structure to the previous one
  temp->next = nouveau;
  // Specifying the NULL pointer to label the last unit
  nouveau->next = NULL;
}


void dumpGroupingOrder( struct groupingOrder* HEAD ) {

  struct groupingOrder* temp = HEAD;
  while( temp != NULL ) {

    // Copying the address of the current unit
    struct groupingOrder* dumpTarget = temp;
    // Storing the address of the next unit before dumping the
    //  current one.
    temp = temp->next;

    // Dumping the current unit and all its allocated variables
    if( dumpTarget->taxa != NULL ) {
      free( dumpTarget->taxa );
      printf( " #" );
    }
    free( dumpTarget );
    printf( "* " );
  }
}


void showGroupingOrder( struct groupingOrder* HEAD ) {

  struct groupingOrder* temp = HEAD;
  while( temp->next != NULL ) {
    temp = temp->next;
    for( int i = 0; i < temp->groupeSize; i++) {
      printf( " %d", temp->taxa[i] );
    }
    printf( " %Lf\n", temp->distance );
  }
}



int main() {
  
  size_t groupeSize[6] = { 2,2,4,2,5,7 };
  int groupes[][7] = { {2,3}, {5,1}, {2,3,5,1}, {7,4}, {2,3,5,1,6}, {2,3,5,1,6,7,4} };

  struct groupingOrder HEAD = { .next = NULL };
  
  for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){

    addGroup( &HEAD, groupes[i], groupeSize[i], 0.0003 );
  }

  showGroupingOrder( &HEAD );
  printf( "\n\n" );
  dumpGroupingOrder( &HEAD );
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post code with line numbers.

Comment: If you post code with line numbers, then it is harder for us to copy&paste the code for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the other answer, the problem is that the head node of your linked list was not allocated by `malloc`. Therefore, you are not allowed to call `free` on that node.

However, in contrast to the other answer, I do not recommend that you fix the problem by leaving out the head node when freeing the memory, but rather to restructure your program so that all nodes (including the head node) are treated equally, so that also the memory for the head node gets allocated by `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


struct groupingOrder {
    int *taxa;
    size_t groupeSize;
    long double distance;
    struct groupingOrder* next;
};


void addGroup( struct groupingOrder** HEAD, int * groupe, size_t groupeSize, long double distance ) {

    struct groupingOrder** temp = HEAD;
    // Make "temp" point to the "next" member of the last node of
    // the list, or if the list is empty, make "temp" point to
    // the pointer to the head node (which has the value NULL).
    while( (*temp) != NULL ) {
        temp = &(*temp)->next;
    }
    // Allocating space for the unit structure
    struct groupingOrder* nouveau = malloc( sizeof( struct groupingOrder ) );
    nouveau->distance = distance;
    nouveau->groupeSize = groupeSize;
    // Allocating variable space for the list of taxa to be stored
    nouveau->taxa = malloc( groupeSize * sizeof( int ) );
    for( int i = 0; i < groupeSize; i++) {
        nouveau->taxa[i] = groupe[i];
    }
    // Specifying the NULL pointer to label the last unit
    nouveau->next = NULL;
    // Linking the new unit structure to the previous one
    *temp = nouveau;
}


void dumpGroupingOrder( struct groupingOrder** HEAD ) {

    struct groupingOrder* temp = *HEAD;
    while( temp != NULL ) {

        // Copying the address of the current unit
        struct groupingOrder* dumpTarget = temp;
        // Storing the address of the next unit before dumping the
        //  current one.
        temp = temp->next;

        // Dumping the current unit and all its allocated variables
        if ( dumpTarget->taxa != NULL ) {
            free( dumpTarget->taxa );
            printf( " #" );
        }
        free( dumpTarget );
        printf( "* " );
    }

    // Mark linked list as empty
    *HEAD = NULL;
}


void showGroupingOrder( struct groupingOrder* HEAD ) {

    for ( struct groupingOrder* temp = HEAD; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next ) {
        
        for( int i = 0; i < temp->groupeSize; i++) {
            printf( " %d", temp->taxa[i] );
        }
        printf( " %Lf\n", temp->distance );
    }
}



int main() {
  
    size_t groupeSize[6] = { 2,2,4,2,5,7 };
    int groupes[][7] = { {2,3}, {5,1}, {2,3,5,1}, {7,4}, {2,3,5,1,6}, {2,3,5,1,6,7,4} };

    struct groupingOrder *HEAD = NULL;
  
    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {

        addGroup( &HEAD, groupes[i], groupeSize[i], 0.0003 );
    }

    showGroupingOrder( HEAD );
    printf( "\n\n" );
    dumpGroupingOrder( &HEAD );
  
    return 0;
}
```

It was necessary for me to modify the function `main` and `addGroup`. I also modified the other two functions, but these changes were not necessary.

This program has the following output:

```
 2 3 0.000300
 5 1 0.000300
 2 3 5 1 0.000300
 7 4 0.000300
 2 3 5 1 6 0.000300
 2 3 5 1 6 7 4 0.000300


 #*  #*  #*  #*  #*  #*
```

Comment: @Goûtay: The head node, if it exists, **is** allocated by `malloc`. However, in the function `main`, I have changed the variable `HEAD` to merely be a pointer which points to the head node, or to `NULL` if the head node does not exist. In your original code, that variable is not a pointer, but rather the head node itself.

Comment: Yes, I did not read carefully enough the `addGroup()` function you edited.
However, if I add a call to `showGroupingOrder( HEAD )` after freeing everything I get a segmentation fault.
Should not the `showGroupingOrder()` function be rewrote as well with a `struct **` as an argument instead of `struct *` to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Goûtay: The function `addGroup` may need to change the value of the pointer `HEAD` in the function `main`, so it needs a pointer to that variable. That is why it needs a pointer to a pointer (`struct groupingOrder**`) as a function parameter. However, the functions `dumpGroupingOrder` and `showGroupingOrder` do not need to change the value of that pointer, so it is sufficient to pass that variable by value, not by pointer. That is why a parameter of type `struct groupingOrder*` is sufficient.

Comment: @Goûtay: After the function `dumpGroupingOrder` is called, all nodes in the linked list get freed, which means that the variable `HEAD` of the function `main` now is a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) (it pointers to something that no longer exists). That is why you get a segmentation fault if you call `showGroupingOrder` after calling `dumpGroupingOrder`. If you want it to print an empty list instead, then you must set the variable `HEAD` to `NULL` to indicate that the list is now empty. You can also change the function `dumpGroupingOrder` to [...]

Comment: @Goûtay: [...] do this, but in that case, you will have to change the function parameter of the function `dumpGroupingOrder` to accept a `struct groupingOrder**` instead of a `struct groupingOrder*`.

Comment: Verstanden. Thank you very much for all these explanations!

Comment: @Goûtay: I have now modified the function `dumpGroupingOrder` to mark the linked list as empty, as described above. You should now be able to call the function `showGroupingOrder` immediately after calling `dumpGroupingOrder` without a segmentation fault occuring. The function `showGroupingOrder` won't print anything though, because the list is empty.

Comment: @Goûtay: Using pointers to pointers (`struct groupingOrder**`) can appear complicated at first, but ultimately, it does make the code simpler and cleaner. I hope that I was able to demonstrate this to you with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `dumpGroupingOrder` tries to free everything in the list, including the `HEAD`.

On the other hand, what is passed from the function `main` as `HEAD` is a pointer to a local variable, not a pointer returned from `malloc()` family.

You mustn't free what are not `NULL` nor things returned from `malloc()` family.

You should change

```c
struct groupingOrder* temp = HEAD;
```

in the function `dumpGroupingOrder` to

```c
struct groupingOrder* temp = HEAD->next;
```

to avoid freeing `HEAD`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it! That and affecting
`HEAD->next = NULL;`
otherwise I will be getting segmentation fault with other functions using the empty structure such as `showGroupingOrder()`.